# How can I retrieve data from two different const and put it in a for

Tags: javascript, for-loop, for-of-loop

This is my code:

```
const data1 = [{ data2:...,data3....}]
const data4 = [{ data5:...,data6:....}]
for (let data2 of data1) {
}
```

I want to retrieve both date2 of date1 and date5 of date 4

Edit: I solved with "for (let data of [data1,data4])"
But now I have another problem, I need to take the value present in all const (in this case it is an ID: 1 field) and pass it to a function, but it returns it to me as undefined.
const are structured like this:

```
const data1 = [{data2: ..., data3 ...., ID = 1}]
const data4 = [{data5: ..., data6: .... ID = 2}]

getdata (data.ID) .done (function () {
});
```

with one const it works with multiple const me gives them undefined
sorry if i'm unclear but i'm still learning.

Comment: do you have some real data and wanted result?

Comment: Pleas provide data example for `date1` and `date4` arrays?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can create a method `getObjByKey`  to find in the provided `arr` array the object that contains `key` property and use [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) the get the value

Code:

```
const getObjByKey = (key, arr) =>
  arr.find((obj) => Object.entries(obj).find(([k, v]) => key === k));
```

Then you can do:

```
const { data2 } = getObjByKey('data2', date1);
const { date5 } = getObjByKey('date5', date4);
```

Code example:

```js
// date1 example based on the question code
const date1 = [{ data1: []}, { data2: [1, 2, 3, 4]}]

const getObjByKey = (key, arr) =>
  arr.find((obj) => Object.entries(obj).find(([k, v]) => key === k))
const { data2 } = getObjByKey('data2', date1)

// Now you do your logic with `data2`
console.log(data2)
```

Comment: I tried but so it only returns the value contained in date 4

Comment: Pleas, in your question, provide data example for both `date1` and `date4` arrays?

Comment: sorry my mistake now go thanks

Comment: Good to help @Francis

Answer (score 0):

Not having a sample of the data/output i would answer like this

```
var data2 = data1[0]['data2'];
var data5 = data4[0]['data5'];
```

Answer (score -1):

This way you should get the keys of the object and you can access to the value

```
 for( i of [data1,data4]){
    let key = Object.keys(i[0]);
    console.log(i[0][key]) 
 }
```